# When I try to store characters in a 2D malloc array, it says "Segementation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to create a simple snake game. This is first part of it, to display the borders of the map using '*' according to user's command line input. However, when I try to create a malloc array and store '*' accordingly, it crashes saying "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". Please help me figure out this error and fix my code. I am new to C programming.

```
         #include<stdio.h>
         #include<stdlib.h>

   void initializeSnake(char** pArray, int pRows, int pColumns, int pSnakeLength);
   void print(char** pArray, int pRows, int pColumns);


 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

 int rows=atoi(argv[1]);
int columns=atoi(argv[2]);
int snakeLength=atoi(argv[3]);

char** mapArray;
mapArray=(char**)malloc(rows*sizeof(char*));
for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
mapArray[i]=(char*)malloc(columns*sizeof(char*));

  initializeSnake(mapArray, rows, columns, snakeLength);
  print(mapArray,rows,columns);

  printf("Rows: %s\n",argv[1]);
  printf("Columns: %s\n",argv[2]);
  printf("Snake Length: %s\n",argv[3]);



  return 0;
    }
   void initializeSnake(char** pArray, int pRows, int pColumns, int pSnakeLength)
 {
    for(int m=0;m<pRows+2;m++)
   {

for(int n=0;n<pColumns+2;n++)
{
  if(m==0 || m==pRows+1)
    pArray[m][n]=42;
  else if(n==0 || n==pColumns+1)
    pArray[m][n]=42;
  else if(m!=1)
    pArray[m][n]=' ';

    if(m==1)
    {
      if(n==0)
        pArray[m][n]='#';
      else if(n>0 && n<pSnakeLength)
        pArray[m][n]='-';
      else if(n==pSnakeLength)
        pArray[m][n]='>';
      else if(n<pColumns)
        pArray[m][n]=' ';

    }

}
   }

 }

  void print(char** pArray, int pRows, int pColumns)
   {
   for(int m=0;m<pRows;m++)
   {
    for(int n=0;n<pColumns;n++)
    {
     printf("%c",pArray[m][n]);
    }
printf("\n");
 }
 }
```

Comment: You can just use `VLA`, `char mapArray[rows +3][columns +3];` A matrix/map of `1000 x 1000` size will take only `1 MiB` on process-stack.

Comment: @Zakk Your 1) is incorrect, you want to allocate space for the thing being pointed to. Since `mapArray` is a `char**`, it points to `char*`, so `sizeof(char*)` is correct. Even better to do `mapArray=malloc(rows*sizeof(*mapArray))` so even if `mapArray` changes types, `*mapArray` will always be the correct one. Along that same point, `mapArray[i]=(char*)malloc(columns*sizeof(char*));` is incorrect, that should be `sizeof(char)`, or omitted entirely since `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1.

Answer (score 0):

You deliberately go outside the array you allocated

You create with size rows * cols

```
char** mapArray;
mapArray = (char**)malloc(rows * sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    mapArray[i] = (char*)malloc(columns * sizeof(char*));
```

Pass this info to initializeSnake

```
initializeSnake(mapArray, rows, columns, snakeLength);
```

Then go beyond the bounds in that function

```
for (int n = 0; n < pColumns + 2; n++)
-----------------------------^^^
```

You end up trying to access 2 more columns than you created, same for rows. I do not know the intent of that +2 so cannot propose a solution. But, as you have discovered, you cannot do what you are currently doing.